# Intune executeAction customTextNotification 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, intune, microsoft-graph-intune

I want to execute action customTextNotification but i am getting error 400 Bad Request.
And I don't have any access to graph explorer and the test device that receives the message. All I have is the code in backend in Java and logs.

Here are the details.

URL
POST beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices/executeAction

Body
{"actionName":"customTextNotification","deviceIds":["single device ID is here"],"notificationTitle":null,"notificationBody":"BF test - 12/8/2023 - 7:34AM EST","deviceName":null}

Roles I see in the token

- Device.Read.All
- DeviceManagementServiceConfig.Read.All
- User.Read.All
- DeviceManagementConfiguration.Read.All
- DeviceManagementManagedDevices.ReadWrite.All
- DeviceManagementManagedDevices.PrivilegedOperations.All
- DeviceManagementApps.Read.All

When I check the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-devices-manageddevice-executeaction?view=graph-rest-beta)
It doesn't really tell me if a field is required. Perhaps I am missing a field.

I want to know what I need to run customTextNotification.